# Connection Between Virtue and Well-Being

Tags: ethics, reference-request

I'm curious if anyone has any suggestions for finding **contemporary** philosophy essays/books (i.e., not Aristotle) which deal with the connection between virtue and well-being.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you want to check out [Elizabeth Anscombe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eudaimonia#Eudaimonia_and_modern_moral_philosophy), her essay "Modern Moral Philosophy" might be considered a "contemporary revival of virtue theory". Apparently she believes that duty based ethics need a legislator, and as she doesn't see one she's suggesting a return to virtue ethics. 
[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtue_ethics#Contemporary_.27Aretaic_turn.27) names quite some contemporary writers on virtue ethics, e.g. MacIntyre and Ricoeur. You can find the names of the essays there.